# Overlay char string with a pattern

Tags: char, abap

I wanna add the missing spaces in a character variable.

For instance bu_partner is char10 and has the value `31`. In a standard database table there is only the value `0000000031`.

I tried the overlay command, but `31` is at the beginning and not at the end.

```
DATA: mask TYPE bu_partner VALUE '0000000000',
      partner TYPE bu_partner.

partner = '31'.

OVERLAY partner WITH mask.

write partner.
```

Output:

`3100000000`

Is there any way to achieve `0000000031`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the appropriate conversion exit as designated by the domain:

[image: conversion exit]

```
DATA: some_value TYPE c LENGTH 10,
      partner    TYPE bu_partner.

some_value = '31'.

CALL FUNCTION 'CONVERSION_EXIT_ALPHA_INPUT'
  EXPORTING
    input  = some_value
  IMPORTING
    output = partner.

WRITE: / partner USING NO EDIT MASK.
```

Be aware that you need to `WRITE ... USING NO EDIT MASK` in this case - if you don't use this addition, the list processing will automatically invoke `CONVERSION_EXIT_ALPHA_OUTPUT` which will eliminate the leading zeroes.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the conversion routine mapped to the domain of bu_partner. You can check that in the domain which is mapped to the data element of bu_partner. I am guessing it would be ALPHA. Which means you should use the FM CONVERSION_EXIT_ALPHA_INPUT to convert external data to internal format  ( if you input 31 then you would get output as 0000000031 ) . If you want to convert internal to external then use the FM CONVERSION_EXIT_ALPHA_OUTPUT where appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

After some digging, I found the command `UNPACK`.

```
DATA: lv_partner_leading_zeros(10) type c,
      lv_partner TYPE bu_partner.

lv_partner = '31'.

UNPACK lv_partner to lv_partner_leading_zeros.
```

Comment: After digging in the wrong places, obviously. This is NOT a valid, generalizeable solution.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your solution @Niklas unpack will work just fine as long as it is always numeric values.

Comment: @Niklas For instance because BU_PARTNER is a character field - you can't simply assume that it will always contain numeric values, and if it doesn't, your program will abort. You can't use this mechanism for input fields that contain more than 31 characters because this will cause a short dump as well.  Your "solution" will also silently chop off leading characters if the target field is too short while the conversion exit will abort with a verbose error message.

Comment: The point with can only unpack numeric values made it. Thanks for sparing me with short dumps in the future.